# Nested JSON and awesomeplete.js

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with the nested JSON file. How do calling the "name"?

**The JSON file**

```
{
  "city": [{
    "name":"Belgium",
    "topLevelDomain":[".be"]
   }]
}
```

**The javascript**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "http://exapmple.com/example.json",true);

ajax.onload = function() {
   var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).map(function(i) { return i.name;});
   new Awesomplete(document.querySelector("#search"),{ list: list });
}; 
ajax.send();
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Umm `responseText` is a JSON string, I'm assuming that, so the function `map` is only available for functors.

Comment: `map` is for arrays.  You need to iterate over an object.

Comment: `var list = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText).city.map(function(i) { return i.name;});`

Comment: @connexo It works, thank you :)

Comment: @Suzhou see the answer hope will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deep search inside object here is how.

```js
var obj=[{
  "city": [{
    "name":"Belgium",
    "topLevelDomain":[".be"]
   }]
}]
function searchInside(object){
    if(object.hasOwnProperty('name'))
        return object.name;

    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(object).length;i++){
        if(typeof object[Object.keys(object)[i]]=="object"){
            o=searchInside(object[Object.keys(object)[i]]);
            if(o!=null)
                return o;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
console.log(searchInside(obj))
```